# Different behavior of ZipOutputStream.setLevel(0) in Linux and Windows env

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

I am trying to optimize a method writeZipResults which take list of ByteOutputStream and convert that into a single zip file as ZipOutputStream.

method definition:

```
public void writeZipResults(Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> files, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    Stopwatch writeZipResultsTimer = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    if(files != null) {
    ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
    for(String filename : files.keySet()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfInMemory = files.get(filename);
        if(pdfInMemory != null) {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename + fileTypes.getExtension());
            zip.putNextEntry(entry);
            pdfInMemory.writeTo(zip);
            zip.closeEntry();
            pdfInMemory.close();
        }
    }
    zip.close();
    logger.info("Took {} ms to complete writeZipResults method, writeZipResultsTimer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILISECONDS));
}
```

}

To optimize above method I added zip.setLevel(0) i.e. no compression which minimized the method execution time to great extend in my local window system.

But when I am running the same code with zip.setLevel(0) in linux environment I am not getting same performance as it is under windows system.

To put my point here is the application logs(highlighted in yellow) from Linux and my local windows system captured for same scenario with exactly same data set:

[image]

```
To add more information:
Java Version: 7
Use case: for set of attributes create pdf file for each attribute and combine all pdf files into zip file and return in http response. All file creation process is in memory.
```

Please suggest how to optimize the method under linux environment?

Comment: I highly doubt that the issue is in the code that you posted. This needs a complete, verifiable example (an [MCVE]).

Comment: @davmac But I added logs inside the method so ideally it should reflect the time taken by method execution  --                                       logger.info("Took {} ms to complete writeZipResults method, writeZipResultsTimer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILISECONDS));

Comment: Do you have the same versions of jre on both systems? Ara they both HotSpot?

Comment: I see the version difference Linux box has version 1.7.0_80 and my local window system has version 1.7.0_21 but verified that it is not due to version change. I tried 1.7.0_80 on my local system.

Comment: I don't see good reason for doing it this way in the first place. All the ByteArrayOutputStreams are just wasting memory you can do with, and adding latency you can do without. Just write them direct to the Zip.